# How can I detect motion in a long, mostly dull video?

Tags: software-recommendation, video

I need a way to scan through hours and hours of **recorded** video (mp4, mov, avi, doesn't matter, I can fix that) to search for motion. The videos consist of many, many hours of dull nature scenes like bird nests or a feeding site where very little happens for long stretches punctuated by short bursts of action like parents switching, feeding, etc.

I can't use a cctv monitoring program because those monitor a live stream and only record when there's action. These videos are recorded way off the grid where any form of internet connection is a distant dream.

I've looked at Zoneminder and Motion, but these don't allow me to switch the input from a live feed to a file. Ideally, I'd like it to scan a whole lot faster than real-time.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I tried the VLC filter, didn't work out for me. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, no, I didn't.

Comment: I am currently working on a windows based software to do this. I will update here once the beta is released in case anyone else needs to do this.

Comment: hello, I have exactly same task. Is there a hope to see a release?

Comment: Related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/12097/filter-motion-in-video-file-surveillance-video

Answer (score 20):

#### [DVR-Scan](https://github.com/Breakthrough/DVR-Scan)

> DVR-Scan is a cross-platform command-line (CLI) application that
>   automatically detects motion events in video files (e.g. security
>   camera footage). In addition to locating both the time and duration of
>   each motion event, DVR-Scan will save the footage of each motion event
>   to a new, separate video clip. Not only is DVR-Scan free and
>   open-source software (FOSS), written in Python, and based on Numpy and
>   OpenCV, it was built to be extendable and hackable.

Usage:

```
dvr-scan -i some_video.mp4 -o some_video_motion_only.avi
```

Comment: Works very well, but it's very slow, too. Analysis takes about 20 min for a 1h video, using a quad core i5-7400. That may be fine in a desktop computer, but in a low resource server (like a Raspberry Pi), analysis can perfectly take more time than the actual video.

Comment: @jesjimher, try the new CNT option. Also try reducing the data using scale and skip options.

Answer (score 13):

#### [VLC](https://snapcraft.io/vlc)

VLC has a motion detection filter that you can try by accessing: *Tools* -> *Effects and Filters* -> *Video Effects* -> *Advanced* -> *Motion Detect*.

[image: screenshot]

You might have more tweaks available running it [from the command line](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/#Video_options) with the `--video-filter=motiondetect` flag; check out [this example](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=89563#p340619).

Comment: I'm not understanding what this is supposed to do - I do not see any change in my video playback when I select this option.

Comment: restart vlc after change setting

Comment: This highlights changes in the video by overlaying white boxes. This may be helpful, but you still have to watch the video.

Comment: For those not able to find this setting, I am using Version 3.0.16 Vetinari on Mac, and I found the setting under Window -> Video Effects... -> Color -> Motion Detect